# Can't run cordova commands on Windows 10

Tags: windows, cordova, sencha-touch

I have created a new project application using Sencha Touch and I want to run it on my Android phone using cordova. I have installed cordova globally on my computer (Windows 10), but none of the commands related to cordova work. Whenever I try to run the create command, all I get is:

> Node Commands
>
> Syntax:
>       node {operator} [options] [arguments]
>
> Parameters:
>           /? or /help   - Display this help message.
>           list          - List nodes or node history or the cluster
>           listcores     - List cores on the cluster
>           view          - View properties of a node
>           online        - Set nodes or node to online state
>           offline       - Set one or more nodes to the offline state
>
> For more information about HPC command-line tools,
>   see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=120724.

The commands I tried to run are:

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

and

```
cordova-cli create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

but not even  **cordova -v** works.
I must say that I have added all the necessary environment variables, tried running the commands using the absolute path, or right from the cordova folder in *AppData\Roaming\npm* and from most of its subfolders.

Comment: Is "cordova" the only command that does not work or all the node related stuffs does not work?

Comment: @Purus Only cordova, anything else installed with npm works fine